# SQL Server stored procedure with views

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-view

I change some entries from a table with a stored procedure and this changes impact a view.

When is the view updating? When the stored procedure is working (after the specific statement) or when it is completed?

I'm using SQL Server 2019 (v15).

Comment: Generally speaking, a view is just a pre-written select statement. There is nothing to "update" - the database engine will execute the select statement in a view when that view is referenced in a tsql statment.

Comment: Is there an insert trigger on the view?

Comment: @SteveC There is no insert trigger

Comment: @SMor Ok, I think I get it..so its always "live"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If you have done schema changes to underlying Tables:

It does not happen automatically. You have to specifically call [sp_refreshsqlmodule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to refresh the view

```sql
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule 'SchemaName.ViewName'
```

> sp_refreshsqlmodule should be run when changes are made to the objects
> underlying the module that affect its definition. Otherwise, the
> module might produce unexpected results when it is queried or invoked.
> To refresh a view, you can use either sp_refreshsqlmodule or
> sp_refreshview with the same results.

You can also use [sp_refreshview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshview-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to refresh view for the underlying changes.

```sql
EXEC sp_refreshview N'SchemaName.ViewName'
```

> If a view is not created with schemabinding, sp_refreshview should be
> run when changes are made to the objects underlying the view that
> affect the definition of the view. Otherwise, the view might produce
> unexpected results when it is queried

It is generally best practice to create views with `SCHEMA BINDING` option, which will avoid schema changes to underlying tables. [Benefits of Schemabinding](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4673/benefits-of-schemabinding-in-sql-server/)

#### If you have done data changes to tables, not schema changes:

View is nothing but a stored SQL Statement. It is a virtual table. When you select from a view, the corresponding table query is being run at run time. View is not storing the data separately. So, no need to update or refresh the view.

Comment: I only change values (rows), not the table structure itself.

Comment: Got it. View is nothing but a stored SQL Statement. It is not holding data. When you call a view, it is getting data from the table only. So, no need to update the view separately.

Comment: @VenkataramanR: you don't **call** a view - you can call a stored procedure or function - something that is code - you **select** from a view ....

Comment: @marc_s, got it. I have updated my answer accordingly. thanks for your clarification words.